# ReferenceError: ResizeObserver is not defined with nivo and NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nivo-react, resize-observer

I want to use nivo with Next but when I load the page containing a pie chart made with nivo, I get this error: `ReferenceError: ResizeObserver is not defined`.

My `Pie.js` component:

```js
import { ResponsivePie } from "@nivo/pie";

export const data = [
  {
    id: "c",
    label: "c",
    value: 80,
    color: "hsl(8, 70%, 50%)",
  },
  {
    id: "lisp",
    label: "lisp",
    value: 188,
    color: "hsl(122, 70%, 50%)",
  },

  {
    id: "go",
    label: "go",
    value: 161,
    color: "hsl(111, 70%, 50%)",
  },
];

export default function MyPie({ data }) {

    return (
        <ResponsivePie
            data={data}
            margin={{ top: 40, right: 80, bottom: 80, left: 80 }}
            innerRadius={0.5}
            padAngle={0.7}
            cornerRadius={3}
            activeOuterRadiusOffset={8}
            borderWidth={1}
            borderColor={{ from: "color", modifiers: [["darker", 0.2]] }}
            arcLinkLabelsSkipAngle={10}
            arcLinkLabelsTextColor="#333333"
            arcLinkLabelsThickness={2}
            arcLinkLabelsColor={{ from: "color" }}
            arcLabelsSkipAngle={10}
            arcLabelsTextColor={{ from: "color", modifiers: [["darker", 2]] }}
            defs={[
            {
                id: "dots",
                type: "patternDots",
                background: "inherit",
                color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)",
                size: 4,
                padding: 1,
                stagger: true,
            },
            {
                id: "lines",
                type: "patternLines",
                background: "inherit",
                color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)",
                rotation: -45,
                lineWidth: 6,
                spacing: 10,
            },
            ]}
        />
    )
};
```

My `chart.js` page:

```js
import MyPie, { data } from "../components/Pie";

import homeStyles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

function Chart() {
  return (
    <div className={homeStyles.divchart}>
      <MyPie data={data}/>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Chart;
```

This error only appears when using `ResponsivePie` and not `Pie`. I also tried to make it work with a React project but though I don't get this error, Nothing seems to be displayed.

**Edit:**

After some investigations, it looks like there is something wrong with `@nivo/core` **0.79.0** dependency. We should open an issue on the GitHub repo. I made some changes to check whether it is caused by my version of Next.js but the bug occurs only with @nivo/core 0.79.0.

Answer (score 11):

It turns out this was the result of a bug introduced in version `0.79.0`, which was fixed in https://github.com/plouc/nivo/pull/1886.

You should update `@nivo/core` to `0.79.1`.

---

It looks like `@nivo/pie` is not compatible with Next.js server-side rendering as it utilizes Web APIs (`ResizeObserver`).

To avoid importing `MyPie` (and subsequently `ResponsivePie`) on the server, you can dynamically import it on the client-side only using [`next/dynamic`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr) with `ssr: false`.

```js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import { data } from "../components/Pie";
import homeStyles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

const MyPie = dynamic(() => import("../components/Pie"), {
    ssr: false
})

function Chart() {
    return (
        <div className={homeStyles.divchart}>
            <MyPie data={data}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Chart;
```

Comment: Yet it works on **0.78.0** and according to the creator of this lib, it is fully server-side compliant. The error was happening with every type of chart (bar, pie, line, etc). Then I would suspect there is a bug in the last `@nivo/core` version unless `resizeObserver` is not used in older versions, which I do not believe

Comment: Then you're most likely correct, it's probably a bug introduced in `0.79.0`. Might be related to this unreleased fix: https://github.com/plouc/nivo/pull/1886.

Comment: That's it, I went on the discord server and he told me he was working on a fix

Comment: Great save using `dynamic` @juliomalves .

Comment: Was there any further update on this? I'm getting this issue with nivo/line, nextjs 12.1.6, and react 18.2. I see there isn't a nivo/core 79.1, only 79.0, unlike all the other packages that have 79.1 and nivo/core 79.0 doesn't support React 18.

Comment: @AlPal You're right, there doesn't seem to be a published version of `@nivo/core` that contains the fix I mentioned. I'd recommend reaching out to nivo maintainers directly on their GitHub repo: https://github.com/plouc/nivo/issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that code is being run on server side (SSR), and `ResizeObserver` doesn't exist there. You should try to make sure that your code only executes when on client side.

It's hard for me to tell you how as I don't know what your setup is. You can likely just add a check to only run that part of the code if `ResizeObserver` is defined.

I hope at least this points you in the right direction.

Comment: As far as I know, my pages are CSR and I don't use any `getServerProps()` nor `getStaticProps()` function. I tried running a fresh Next project and installing `@nivo/core`and `@nivo/pie` but the error keeps showing whereas I follow all the steps (except installing "nivo" since I trust the official docs and it is not working when `npm i nivo`) described here: https://learnjsx.com/category/4/posts/nextjs-nivo

Comment: Actually the problem occurs randomly

Comment: So I made an observation: I ran the server and used `Pie` instead of `ResponsivePie` and once the page was loaded, I changed my code to `ResponsivePie` which displayed the pie but if I refresh the page, I get the error back. I cannot explain this...